# Qt focus popup window or mainwindow

Tags: c++, qt, graphical-interaction

I would like to have a MainWindow, and from it, open a popup window for showing some information. And I would like to bring to the front the which one I select doint click on some of them. There is a good example in Qt samples, but it is using QML. I would not like to use qml for the moment.

[image]

I have already my MainWindow class, and I think I need to use a QDialog for creating the popup window, no?? Or QWidget?? The idea is showing a charts in that popup.

```
// Constructor
VDLandMarkDemo::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    // Some Initializations 
}

// Destructor
MainWindow::~MainWindow(){delete ui;}


void MainWindow::on_graphics_clicked()
{

    chartwindow = new QDialog;
    chartwindow->activateWindow();

    // Some code chart relate on

    chartwindow->show();
}
```

EDIT1: I have found finally the solution to my question in this post:
[Qt: How to give focus to a modeless QDialog created from the main window when the main window is blocked by a modal QDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609481/qt-how-to-give-focus-to-a-modeless-qdialog-created-from-the-main-window-when-th)
Thanks anyway.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try, so far? Can you post some code? And what's the question by the way?

Comment: Done! Thanks for the interest @p-a-o-l-o

Comment: Still I don't get the question.

Comment: The question is that just now I can open a Dialog window,  but my main window is always in the background... Behind my new popup window. And I want it comes to the front if I click with the mouse on it. But now, it does not work.

Is there some way without using mouse events?

Thanks.

Comment: Already solved. Thanks and sorry for not explaining it well.

Comment: Yes @eyllanesc . I do not exactly if it is duplicated or not. And I do not know if I should to close this post. Maybe some of you have more experience than me and could tell me. :)

Comment: @Arritmic If the answer for both cases is the same, practically your answer refers to the other answer, then it is a duplicate, and therefore we close the community, closes it with more privileges or you eliminate it.

Comment: @eyllanesc The question is not the same, but I have found the solution for my problem there.

Comment: If the solution works for this question, it should be marked as a duplicate and both questions should be left in place. There's no reason to delete this question because it can still be useful as a "signpost" to the other answer.